# How to give IDs to Objects to use in any method?

Tags: c#, .net, object, properties

I'm coming into C# from the JavaScript language and I can't seem to find a way to assign string ID names to objects in my Form application that can be used in many methods. For example,

```
string inputNameBox = textbox1.Text;
```

I want to be able to use "inputNameBox" in any method. If I assign inputNameBox inside a click event for a button, everything works properly. But I want to be able to call inputNameBox in another method without giving a new string ID to textbox1.Text.

I tried using static strings and constants, but they returned error. I also tried setting them as properties but the value = null.

How can I use the same string ID for the .Text object in any method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a property:

```
public string InputNameBox
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: This works! I wasn't setting the proper values for the get and set.

Answer (score 0):

You can acomplish this using data bindings.